# MVVM Light Toolkit samples

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, toolkit, mvvm-light

Does anyone know opensource WPF applications created using MVVM Light Toolkit? Or any samples?

Comment: I would like to see some samples as well, specifically for WPF.

Comment: I ran across this link a few months ago. This example contains quite a few references to telerik controls, but the overall architecture of the application is fairly straightforward http://blogs.telerik.com/rosswozniak/posts/10-05-06/task-it_video_and_blog_post_index.aspx

Comment: I would like to see samples that don't require Expression Blend - craziness.

Comment: One of the reasons I switched to Caliburn Micro.

Answer (score 37):

Well I wrote a note taking app using mvvm light, if you wanna check the code:

[ApuntaNotas](http://apuntanotas.codeplex.com/)

It's true that MVVM Light is lacking of big examples... We need to create that examples :)

Comment: Thanks dude. Your example got me started with the Messaging stuff in MVVMLight - compiled first try, direct and to the point (other examples tried to be too clever, wouldn't compile unless i spent time setting up the right SL environment, etc etc)

Comment: At the time of writing this there was no `Set<T>(...)`?

Answer (score 8):

There are not many **public** applications using the MVVM Light Toolkit. I know a few applications that use it, but I cannot always talk about it unfortunately. Probably it is just too new.

I am currently very busy writing a Silverlight book, but my plan is, as soon as I will be done writing, to create a reference application on Codeplex and to implement it in WPF and in Silverlight. In the mean time, if anyone else wants to create samples, let me know :)

Laurent

Comment: Can you provide samples on how to use the messenger class?

Comment: For the Messenger, see my MIX10 video where I show an introduction to this class:
http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX14

Also, check a much more meaty sample here:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/10/18/clean-shutdown-in-silverlight-and-wpf-applications.aspx

Comment: The best example of usage of MVVM Light for me was MVVM Light Toolkit Fundamentals (Pluralsight). I have not found any better example (ApuntaNotas is quite good but it is lack of useful things, i.e. snippets)

Comment: The course I published at Pluralsight has multiple samples in various frameworks. Check the documentation page at http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc

Answer (score 7):

I have T4 code templates that generate your view/viewmodel for mvvm light and also other tricks. [Download here](http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/MVVMT4-1-0-0-0)

[Also see this example using MVVM Light and MEF](http://rickrat.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-mef-to-link-view-model-locator-and-load-assembly-uis-dynamically/)

Comment: Can not open the sites.

Comment: http://nuget.org/packages?q=MVVMT4

Answer (score 7):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionForSilverlight.aspx

Comment: That one is fantastic. Very in-depth example. I learnt a great deal on architecture with this one.

Answer (score 4):

Laurent, MVVM Light's author wrote an article in the latest MSDN Magazine: [Using the MVVM Pattern in Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't have any code myself but have a look at Shawn Wildermuth's blog, he has done an example app http://wildermuth.com/ 
It's Silverlight and also uses RIA services, but hte basics should be on target.

John Papa occassional has sone stuff up as well http://johnpapa.net.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a **Coding Dojo** for Silverlight - Blend and MVVMLight.

http://www.alphablog.org/2011/08/07/coding-dojo-silverlight/

Take a look and see if it fits to your needs.