# Have object send message to MainPage

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, data-binding, static

I have a class `Target` and a static property, in another class, called `points`. Each time the user hits a target, I want to increase the points. The reason I put `points` in a different static class is so that each `Target` object can access it. 
The problem is that the textblock displaying the points exists in the MainPage and not in each Target object. Since I can't bind my XAML to a static property, how can I make it so that each Target object can somehow let the MainPage know that it should update the points textblock? thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could totally apply the MVVM pattern here. If there is a static **ViewModel** that is bound to the main window, then you can raise a notification each time a property changes and the **Views** (all tied windows that display the data) will be automatially updated (re-bound).

I would recommend checking Laurent Bugnion's [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) framework. It has a lot of this plumbing done for you, so all that needs to be done from your side is to put the parts together and bind them correctly.

Some resources worth checking for your situation:

- [WPF Apps With The
  Model-View-ViewModel Design
  Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (still applied to
  Silverlight as a methodoloogy)
- [Model-View-ViewModel In Silverlight
  2 Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx)

If you need samples, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687172/mvvm-light-toolkit-samples).

Answer (score 0):

Are Class Target and AnotherClass.points within the same name space? If so, may be the following helps:

```
/* In Window class */
Window w = new Window();

/* function where Target get hit */
w = this;
/* code to update points */
w.textbox1.Text = AnotherClass.points.ToString();
```